# Iterating in XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have the following XSL:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
  <xsl:param name='width' select ="270"/>
  <xsl:param name='height' select="180"/>
  <xsl:variable name="counter" select="0" />
  <xsl:template name="while">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
      <line x1="{$counter}" y1="0.5" x2="{$counter}" y2="10.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
      <xsl:variable name="counter" select="$counter + 10" />
      <xsl:if test="$counter &lt; $width">
        <xsl:call-template name="while"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm trying to get a line drawn every 10pixels across the width, like ruler markings.

When I run this code, it gets stuck in a loop. I can't debug, I just get a stack overflow exception. I presume either my counter value isn't increasing by 10, or that my evaluation of checking if the counter < width is incorrect.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Two people answered, if it had just been you, I would have marked yours as the answer. Daniel's answer included the more helpful wording I felt, coincidentally he also wrote the code. But I didn't ask for that, neither had I written zero code. I don't think I've abused the intentions of this site here. Sorry you feel so irked.

Comment: Well, not irked, just a bit sad since I was going to add the correction in your code, but instead I try to lead you to the solution since you ask for it specifically. And also because it was the solution to the problem and was posted first. Nevermind.

Comment: Aha, sorry Felipe, I understand what you mean now. I've given your post an upvote. Hints help me to search for the correct answer myself, getting the actual code is good for my program, but I don't learn as much in the long run. I was too tempted by the copy and paste solution! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the count to your template by using `xsl:with-param`.

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name='width' select ="270"/>
    <xsl:param name='height' select="180"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">          
            <xsl:call-template name="while"/>
        </svg>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="while">
        <xsl:param name="currentCount" select="0"/>
        <line x1="{$currentCount}" y1="0.5" x2="{$currentCount}" y2="10.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <xsl:variable name="counter" select="$currentCount + 10" />
        <xsl:if test="$counter &lt; $width">
            <xsl:call-template name="while">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentCount" select="$counter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to pass the params when calling your template.

Something like:

```
<xsl:template name="loop">
    <xsl:param name="count" select="1"/>

    <xsl:if test="$count > 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="loop">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

        <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>  
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>

    </xsl:if>    
</xsl:template>
```